# Using context values to update React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a form that will be prepopulated with some data that is returned by an api. My problem is that after my apis run and update context values, the react state is not updating as expected.

I am getting my api data from context:

```
  const {
    submissionDetails,
  } = useContext(AppContext) as {
    submissionDetails: {
      branchName: string
      clientAddress1: string
      clientAddress2: string
      clientCity: string
      clientContactEmail: string
      clientContactFullName: string
      clientName: string
      clientState: string
      clientZip: string
      namedInsured: string
      underwriterDisplayName: string
    }
  }
```

I have console logged my context values and they are as expected.

I am using React state to set my form with the values from context:

```
  const [referralData, setReferralData] = useReducer(referralReducer, {
    accountName: submissionDetails?.namedInsured || '',
    branch: submissionDetails?.branchName || '',
    clientName: submissionDetails?.clientName || '',
    underwriter: submissionDetails?.underwriterDisplayName || '',
  })

  function referralReducer(
    state: {
      accountName: string
      branch: string
      clientName: string
      underwriter: string
    },
    event: { name: string; value: string | unknown }
  ) {
    return { ...state, [event.name]: event.value }
  }
```

Now the problem I am having is that my form still appears to have empty strings for its values.  I would like my reducer to update with the state values whenever they become available.